# Shared models between two Django projects and ForeignKey to a model that exists only in one of them

Tags: django, django-models

I have two Django projects that communicate with each other. The first one contains model `A` and `B` that has a `ForeignKey` to `A`. The first project sends and receives serialized `B` objects from the second project. I want the second project to contain just `B`, but it needs the value of that `ForeignKey`. These models are defined as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(to='A', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ...
```

The problem is that `ForeignKey` to `A` in model `B` requires model `A` to be defined in the second project. Its objects also have to exist so that the database is consistent and there are no problems, e.g., in the admin panel.

In the end, I'd like to treat the `fk` field as a full-fledged `ForeignKey` in the first project and as some kind of read-only generic identifier in the second one. Specifically, I need to retain the functionality of querying both ways in the first project, e.g., `fk__some_a_field` and `b_set`. I would like to have the same code base for the model in both projects to ensure databases in the two projects stay synchronized. How can I achieve this in a clean way?

EDIT:
I was also considering `fk = CustomField(...)` which would be more or less defined as

```
if IS_FIRST_PROJECT:
    CustomField = ForeignKey
else:
    CustomField = IntegerField
```

but the issue is that I'd need a clean way to select the type of integer field that exactly matches the default foreign key. Also, I am not sure if such a solution could bring unexpected problems.

Comment: Hint: Consider developing in terms of _django apps_ rather than projects. Have these two models in separate apps and reuse the apps in your projects.

Comment: I'm curious - do the two projects share/use the same database, or is it two databases with the same table(s) in them? How do you handle db migrations for that project structure?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I already do, but I don't want all models to be serialized and carried over to the second project.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko The two projects are on separate servers, do not share database, and one of them is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Specifically, I need to retain the functionality of querying both ways in the first project, e.g., fk__some_a_field and b_set.

If you want to use django orm, you would have to recreate your A model from project 1 in project 2. But as model A is managed by the project 1, consider adding next lines to your model in project 2:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'your database table name where A model is stored'
```

`managed=False` would tell django to ignore migrations for it, and django won't be allowed to change that model's database table.

The other solution if you don't want to duplicate models from project 1 to project 2, is to not use django orm. And write sql queries by yourself. But as you mentioned you don't want to do this

`P.S` if you don't know how to see name of database table for model A, you can output it like this: `a_model_instance._meta.db_table`, or look it in some tools like pgadming if you are using postgres

Comment: Can you have a `ForeignKey` to a model that is not managed?

Comment: @Xilexio , you can use char field or integer instead of foreign key, and save id of another object in it

Comment: But anyways, you can't use django orm without creating models

Comment: Would having a `ForeignKey` to `A` which is not managed cause errors or just make it an integer (also in Django admin)? Assuming that would cause errors, I could have some variable that tells me which project I'm in (`IS_FIRST_PROJECT`). Would that help?

Comment: @Xilexio , if database between projects is not shared, you can use IntegerField as id of model you are referencing in your other projects, but this will of course break a bit your admin(it won't show any errors, just it won't be working as default foreign key), as integer field would be shown instead of reference, and I don't know what about orm. On database level django ForeignKey is just IntegerField to id of another object. So making it integer field would not cause any errors neither at db and django, but you will lose some django features